Prove any closed walk of odd length contains a cycle of odd length
I know two proofs for any closed walk of odd length contains a cycle of odd length, one is through induction and the other is starting from the shortest closed walk. However, I am confused about the second method.
Let us take an odd closed walk $W=v_1, \ldots, v_k, v_1$ of minimal length, and show that $W$ is a cycle. If $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are distinct then $W$ is a cycle. So suppose that there are $1 \leq i<j \leq k$ with $v_i=v_j$. Consider the following two closed walks: $W_1=v_i, v_{i+1}, \ldots, v_{j-1}, v_j=v_i$ and $W_2=v_1, \ldots, v_i, v_{j+1}, \ldots, v_k, v_1$. Then $E(W)$ is the disjoint union of $E\left(W_1\right)$ and $E\left(W_2\right)$. Hence, $e(W)=e\left(W_1\right)+e\left(W_2\right)$. Since $e(W)$ is odd, one of $e\left(W_1\right), e\left(W_2\right)$ must be odd. But $W_1, W_2$ are closed walks which are shorter than $W$. So we get a contradiction to the minimality of $W$.

I think the proof only shows that the shortest odd closed walk is a cycle. Then how can we show any odd closed walk contains an odd cycle using that?


An odd closed walk has some number of odd closed subwalks, but at least one (itself). One of the odd closed subwalks is a shortest one. The proof shows that such an odd closed subwalk is a cycle. That seems to finish the proof; is this outline convincing?

As @GregMartin points out, the proof is saying that $W$ is of minimal length among odd closed walks, not among all closed walks.  I think that's where your confusion lies.  It then goes on to show that if $W$ is not a cycle, it contains a proper closed walk of odd length, contradicting minimality.

So the shortest means the 'local' shortest, not the 'global' one.
